# Generate a random symmetric binary matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random, binary

I've looked for several question on SO but couldn't find this or figure it out how to do it. I want to generate a random [symmetric](http:///https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) binary matrix (n x n), from a given n.

Examples (n=3):

```
    0 0 1         0 0 1 
    0 0 1   or    0 0 0
    1 1 0         1 0 0
```

I also need the main diagonal to be zero. I know how to do it later, but in case one already want to implement it in an optimal code...

Comment: A common way to make a symmetric matrix is to sum it with its transpose.  Keeping values binary requires a bit extra work, but not much.

Comment: @Kelly it is, by rotation

Comment: @Kelly I know this is not the mathematical definition, this is nevertheless not false given OP's example

Comment: @Oalvinegro can you update your question to explain unambiguously your definition of symmetric?

Comment: @mozway the definition of Symmetric matrix is precise, as mentioned by Kelly. IN any case, I updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: @Oalvinegro thanks for clarifying, then your example is incorrect ;) I thought you wanted a custom transform by rotation.

Comment: @mozway and Kelly, tks! I corrected the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could xor a random matrix with its transpose:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n))
a ^= a.T
```

Comment: (maybe inspired by hpaulj's comment, don't remember)

Comment: Perfect! What does  ^= means in python?

Comment: @Oalvinegro See the third word in my answer.

Comment: @Oalvinegro Bit odd that you declare it perfect without knowing what it does :-D

Comment: Tks, it worked exactly in the way I needed, so I declared it perfectly rs.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a random array and fill one triangle with the 180° rotation of the array. Finally, fill the diagonal with 0.

```
N = 3
a = np.random.randint(2,size=(N,N))
a[np.tril_indices(N)] = np.rot90(a, k=2)[np.tril_indices_from(a)]
np.fill_diagonal(a, 0)
```

Alternatively, you can use a XOR that is faster (X^Y yields 1 if X is different from Y):

```
N = 3
a = np.random.randint(2,size=(N,N))
(a^np.rot90(a, k=2))
np.fill_diagonal(a, 0)
```

Example with N=3:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Example with N=5:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
a = np.tril(np.random.randint(0, 2, (n,n)), -1)
print(a + a.T)
```

`-1` in [`tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) sets all elements above the diagonal just below the main diagonal to zero, so it effectively sets the main diagonal to zero.